# How can I get a string that shows the integer number of seconds since 1970?

Tags: c#

Here's what I tried so far:

```
var value = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds.ToString()
```

It gives me the answer below but I would like to get a whole number:

"1500092088.9501"

Comment: So... you're looking for instructions on how to [round to an integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: whats the output of this code?

Comment: @danyolgiax this is not a duplicate. the question you link is showing how to get a total second difference, Ops question already gets the difference and required rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are a few examples of various ways you can deal with this sort of scenario

```
double secondsSince1970 = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

// int logic. ints are whole numbers so casting to an int will drop all decimals with no rounding.
Console.WriteLine(((long)secondsSince1970).ToString());

// Math logic. .Net gives us some handy Maths to work with rounding decimals
// Round up
Console.WriteLine(Math.Ceiling(secondsSince1970).ToString());
// Round down
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(secondsSince1970).ToString());
// Round nearest
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(secondsSince1970).ToString());
```

EDIT: Changed the int logic to cast to a `long` instead of an `int` because the `int.MaxValue` will be reached near the start of the year 2038

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `DateTimeOffset` to get the seconds count:

```
long secsSinceEpoch = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

This seems to be what you're looking for though, of course, you'd probably want to call `ToString()` on that if you want it as an actual string:

```
var secsSinceEpoch = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
```

Comment: Would that also give numbers after the decimal? I would like to get a whole number.

Comment: No, because it's a long, not a double.

Comment: A "whole" number does not have a decimal, it is an integer

Comment: Your approach interested me so I did a quick benchmark and while this is the sort of operation that likely won't need optimization, I thought I'd share the results anyway just out of interest.
Casting the datetime total seconds runs 10000000 loops in approximately 588 milliseconds while the  DateTimeOffset ToUnixTimeSeconds runs 10000000 loops in 2111 milliseconds. So it's about 4x slower

Comment: @Alan this answer does seem to address your requirements and it's less lines of code which could be good for your situation. Unless you're doing millions of iterations with this logic, the performance is totally fine.

Comment: I guess one problem with this is I am running on WIndows and UtcNow does not seem to have .ToUnixTimeSeconds()

Comment: @Alan the `ToUnixTimeSeconds` method is available on the `DateTimeOffset` type, It won't exist directly on a `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

I thought it worth mentioning - If you want the number of seconds from the start of the epoch time, which is 1/1/1970, You don't need to do subtraction... You just need to get the current datetime and do the conversion to seconds.

Joe_DM provides a good answer to your rounding problem.

(Would leave as comment, but still a little short on rep :) )